# Kali Linux on Virtual Box

Tags: virtualbox, login, kali-linux

Kali Linux booted but stuck on cursor (login) with the black screen. What should I do? I have already reinstalled Virtual Box & Kali Linux.

[image: Kali Linux]

Comment: have you tried rescue mode. or can you check the boot time screen, were it stucks

Comment: have you tried typing `root` enter `toor` ?

Comment: To add to Mongrel's comment have you REMOVED 'quiet splash' form the linux line  in grub  would look similiar to:  vmlinuz-4.7.0-0.rc5.git0.1.fc25.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/secure_fedora-root ro crashkernel=256M rd.luks.uuid=luks-2b90c02c-0478-4d8d-b13f-9cd71146425d rd.lvm.lv=secure_fedora/root rd.lvm.lv=secure_fedora/usr rd.shell nomodeset syskernel.trigger=1 debug=all printk keepearly LANG=en_US.UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

In my case the *Version* value in the machine's *General*/*Basic* settings was `Ubuntu (32 bit)` where my image was 64 bit. I changed it to `Ubuntu (64 bit)` and the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your screen click **view** then select **switch to scaled view**. I had the same problem and this fixed it. For some reason Kali doesn't recognize the display. Same thing happened when I installed scientific linux.

Answer (score 0):

You might have tried to run 64-bit Kali image as a 32 bit OS. I ran into similar scenario with image from https://www.osboxes.org/kali-linux/. By default virtualBox selects 32-bit OS which is why it didn't work for me in the first place.
I had to delete the VM and create a new VM by selecting 64 bit OS.

NOTE:
Editing the VM version did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Found a working solution [HERE](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=99786).

Quoting:

> Turning off Hyper-V from programs and features wasn’t enough. The
> below command worked as many others have used as well. Virtualization
> security in msinfo32 needs to be disabled and this is the only way I
> got it to work.
>
> Enter this command: bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
>
> Enter this command: shutdown -s -t 2